# Different answers of same differentiation Question with two different methods

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Question:- Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ if $$\arccos\bigg({\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}}\bigg)=\arctan( a)$$

$$\arccos\bigg({\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}}\bigg)=\arctan( a)$$

$$\implies  \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}=\cos(\arctan(a))$$

> Taking derivative on both sides w.r.t $\space x$, **we get** $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}$

Out of fun, I tried the substitution $y^2=x^2\cos(\theta)$ and got

$$\frac{1-\cos(\theta)}{1+\cos(\theta)}=\cos(\arctan(a))$$ for $x\ne 0$

$$\implies \tan^2{\frac{\theta}{2}}=\cos(\arctan(a))$$

Differentiate both sides w.r.t $\space \theta$, we get

$$\tan{\frac{\theta}{2}}\bigg(1+\tan^2{\frac{\theta}{2}}\bigg)=0$$

$$\implies \tan{\frac{\theta}{2}}=0$$

$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{1-\tan^2{\frac{\theta}{2}}}{1+\tan^2{\frac{\theta}{2}}}=1$$

> As $y^2=x^2\cos(\theta)$,this gives $y^2=x^2$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}=\pm 1$ Which contradicts the other method, So What's wrong with the $2^{nd}$ method?

Comment: could you please end what I started?

Comment: @janmarqz Yes I'll edit in unedited part.

Comment: outstanding! : D

Comment: I think your substitution is wrong , on substituting you get $\tan\frac{\theta}{2}=\cos(\cdots)$ whch may  not be true for all $\theta$

Comment: The substitution $y^2 = x^2\cos(\theta)$ only works for $\cos(\theta) \ge 0$. In addition, $$\frac{1 + \cos \theta}{1-\cos \theta} = \cos(\arctan(a))$$ says that the function on the LHS is a constant, but this is impossible if $\theta$ is to vary continuously.

Comment: @fwd If that is the case then In $\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}=\cos(\arctan(a))$, RHS is constant and $x$ on LHS is varying then that should also be impossible.

Comment: In that case, the function on the LHS is a function of 2 variables (say $f(x,y)$)and we may identify $\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2 + y^2} = K$ as a level curve, yes $f(x,y)$ is constant for all pairs $x,y$ on that curve.

Comment: @fwd One thing I didn't understand How that one simple substitution creates this type of impossible situation? Does that mean substitution can create such problems in others questions as well.

Comment: When you make a substitution, you have to take into account the range of values for which it is possible.

Comment: @fwd Also can you please explain how $\cos(\theta) \ge 0$ in substitution creates problem in Question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127378/discussion-between-fwd-and-user-1207).

Comment: It may help to visualize this problem in desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/t5vvzfcmn7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In more detail, suppose that for some constant $c$

$$ c =\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}. \tag{1} $$

Note that this is undefined iff $\,x^2+y^2 = 0.\,$
Solve this for $\,y\,$ explicitly to get

$$ y = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1-c}{1+c}}x = \pm C\, x. \tag{2}$$

Take the implicit differential of equation $(1)$ to get

$$ 0 = \frac{4 x y (x\, dy - y\, dx)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}. \tag{3}$$

This implies that $\,\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}\,$
assuming that $\,x^2+y^2\ne 0\,$ and $\,x\ne 0.\,$
Note that $\,\frac{dy}{dx}=-1\,$ is true if $\,y=-x,\,$
but even in this case, $\, \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}\,$
so there is no contraction.

In other words, if $\,y = \pm C\,x,\,$ then
$\, \frac{dy}{dx} = \pm C = \frac{y}{x}. $

By the way, you can't

> Differentiate both sides w.r.t $\,\theta$

because the explicit solution in equation $(2)$ implies that
$\,\theta\,$ is a **constant**.

Comment: Is $y= \pm x$ solution of the orignal equation because in $2^{nd}$ method at the end we got $y^2=x^2$. I'm confused WHAT does $y^2=x^2$ mean at the end and HOW is it related to the equation $\arccos\bigg({\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}}\bigg)=\arctan( a)$?